# Eclipse changed package view to folder view in Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, package, directory

I have the Problem that Eclipse shows all my packages as normal folders. I have to get back to the normal package View because in the folder view the most plugins like Windowbuilder are not working.
I already tried to change the Package Presentation -> Flat or Hierarchical no change.
I tried to add the folder or the Project as Source Folder but the he is using the he is using the first Folder as a Package and the subfolder also e.g.

```
the Folder 
   org
       eclipse
              wb
                swt
       tempuri
are shown as 
   org
       eclipse.wb.swt
       tempuri
but I need 
   org.eclipse.wb.swt
   org.tempuri
```

does anyone have a solution for this?
thx for help
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem generally appears if you delete a folder and did not consider any adjustment on other structure under that folder. The best thing is to go to the package explorer and click on " Source > Build Path>use as source folder". Refresh the project and restart the eclipse.
I have been through this situation couple of times, and it always works for me. Sorry, if I didnt understand your question properly.

Comment: thx that is correct I allready did this. but I had my Package Presentation on Hierarchical and it looks differnt 
:(

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for (at least in the Luna Release (4.4.0)) is the **Package Explorer** view instead of the Navigator view.

You can toggle it from the Window tab:

*Window > Show Menu > Package Explorer*

Answer (score 1):

In Package Explorer tab, click the little triangle next to Link with Editor called View Menu, then choose Package Presentation > Hierarchical.